# Swiftで辞書内辞書を作る方法

Tags: swift

Swiftで以下のようなJSON文字列を作成したいと考えています。

```
{"testDict": {"aaa": 0.0, "bbb": 0.0, "ccc": 0.0}}
```

試しに以下のように書いてみたのですが、エラーが出ます。

```
var testJsonMap = Dictionary<String,Any>()
testJsonMap["testDict"] = Dictionary<String,Any>()

for testObj in ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
{
    testJsonMap["testDict"][testObj] = 0.0
}
```

エラー内容は以下のようなものです。

```
Value of type 'Any?' has no subscripts
```

どうしたら辞書内辞書を生成することができますでしょうか？

Comment: 「JSON文字列を作成」と言うのであれば、最近のSwiftであれば、辞書型など作らずに`Codable`を使ってタイプセーフにやると言うのが流行です。`"aaa", "bbb"`なんて抽象化せずに本物のデータにできるだけ近い形で例を示していただいた方が、最近のやり方を覚えられると思いますよ。

Comment: @OOPer さん、おっしゃる通りですね。質問タイトルの通りで答えてしまいました（おそらく`Codable`は辞書型でAnyの辛さを覚えてからでないとより深く理解できないかなと思います。`Codable`は`Codable`で型を書きまくらないと（クラスを作りまくらないと）いけないので、必要であれば、回答しやすいように @gncc さんには具体的なJSONを書いていただいて別途質問いただいた方がよいかもしれないですね）

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi さん、詳細がわからない状態で「Codableの方が良いですよ、そのための情報を出しなさい」なんて言い方もできないですから、回答されたことも内容も全然問題ないと思いますよ。一つの可能性として提示しておけば、gncc さんが興味を持たれればまた別途質問項目を立てられるだろうと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こういうときは、型を自分で書かないで型推論させるとやりやすいと考えます。

```
var value = [
    "testDict": [
        "aaa": 0.0,
        "bbb": 0.0,
        "ccc": 0.0
    ]
]
print(value)
```

上記コードをXcodeで書き、`value`にXcodeでマウスカーソルを当て、オプションキーを押しながらクリックすると型推論した結果の型を教えてくれます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ということで、あなたが作りたい型が`[String: [String: Double]]`だとわかりますので、

```
var testJsonMap = [String: [String: Double]]()
testJsonMap["testDict"] = [String: Double]()

for testObj in ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
{
    testJsonMap["testDict"]?[testObj] = 0.0
}

print(testJsonMap)
```

で完成です。

コメントを受けての追記:

> ありがとうございます。仮に、{"testDict": {"aaa": 0.0, "bbb": 0.0, "ccc": 0.0}, "testName":"Taro", "testAge":20}などのように、あとから要素が増やしていく場合、var testJsonMap = String: [String: Double]は必ず最初の定義を変えていかないといけないのでしょうか？

```
var value = ["testDict": ["aaa": 0.0, "bbb": 0.0, "ccc": 0.0], "testName":"Taro", "testAge":20] as [String : Any]
print(value)

value["AA"] = ["BB":"CC"]
print(value)
```

なんてこともできました。（これはJavaScriptでなく、SwiftなのでAnyは基本的に使いたくないのが、私の個人的な感想です）。

はじめに空の辞書を作る場合は下記のように書けました。

```
var value = [String : Any]()
print(value)

value["AA"] = ["BB":"CC"]
value["num"] = 10.0
print(value)
```

さらにコメントを受けての追記:

> value = ["testDict": ["aaa": 0.0, "bbb": 0.0, "ccc": 0.0]]に対して["testDict": ["aaa": 0.0, "bbb": 0.0, "ccc": 0.0,"ddd":0.1]]のように追加していく方法はありますか？value["testDict"] = ["ddd":0.1]としてしまうと上書きされてしまうので上書きせずに追加したいです。

確かに直接やろうとすると、`Value of type 'Any?' has no subscripts`というエラーが出てしまいますね。

Anyでは型情報がなくなってしまうため、下記のようにすればできます。
（果たしてここまでしてAnyが使いたいかは微妙なところだと私は考えますが）

```
var value = ["testDict": ["aaa": 0.0, "bbb": 0.0, "ccc": 0.0], "testName":"Taro", "testAge":20] as [String : Any]
print(value)

if var testDict = value["testDict"] as? [String: Any]{
    testDict["ddd"] = 0.1
    value["testDict"] = testDict
}

print(value)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。仮に、{"testDict": {"aaa": 0.0, "bbb": 0.0, "ccc": 0.0}, "testName":"Taro", "testAge":20}などのように、あとから要素が増やしていく場合、var testJsonMap = [String: [String: Double]]()は必ず最初の定義を変えていかないといけないのでしょうか？

Comment: @gncc さん　追記しました。

Comment: value = ["testDict": ["aaa": 0.0, "bbb": 0.0, "ccc": 0.0]]に対して["testDict": ["aaa": 0.0, "bbb": 0.0, "ccc": 0.0,"ddd":0.1]]のように追加していく方法はありますか？value["testDict"] = ["ddd":0.1]としてしまうと上書きされてしまうので上書きせずに追加したいです。